# Extract name from input inside of string in smarty

Tags: html, smarty

I was wondering if there is a possibility to extract attributes from a string in Smarty.

Sample:

```
{$mySmartyArray}
//This array contains 
//Array( 0 => "<input name='aaa' />",
//       1 => "<input value='' name='bbb' placeholder='' />",
//       2 => "<input placeholder='foobar' name='ccc' />"
//     );
```

What I want to achieve is something like:

```
<select name="{$mySmartyArray[0]:attr[name]}">
```

Of course, I know this looks kind of crap, but I'm looking for some kind of selector.

Or am I supposed to do this with a dirty `strpos` search ?

Or is a regular expression a possibility?

The task is:

PHP calls some functions and creates the smarty stuff. Now I want to replace the inputs in the array with some select-options.

I'm about to create a smarty plugin to do something like:

```
<select name="{preg_match value=$mySmartyArray[0] pattern='myRegExHere'}">
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

Which brings me to my next question: What would be the regex for selecting this?

Comment: 1.why is it in an array? 2. is it meant to know that 0 index and 2 index names are different in terms of there usage. 3. cant this not be done client  side using something like jquery as it looks like html. 4. sozs was confused cozs of your wording... strings don't have attributes.. html does... maybe update title, to reflect the correct question.

Comment: are u using a frame work.... like angular, my guess is that yes there is probably a much smarter what to do this.... i think you should provide more info tho.

Comment: 1. thats the way the data gets received, actually I dont know why, but thats how it is :) 2. atm all inputs are the same, only difference is the name value. But I dont know if this will be like this for ever so to prevent errors I swapped the name entry a bit. 3. no it cant, since php comes up with that content end fills it into smarty arrays i cant manipulate them with jquery. Task ist to replace input with '<select><option>'. Im about to write a smarty plugin to call preg_match in smarty...

Comment: to your question.. yes im using a framework (template system) smarty ^^

Answer (score 0):

I added a Plugin to solve my problem:

```
function smarty_function_preg_match($params, &$smarty)
{

    if (!empty($params['pattern']) && !empty($params['subject'])) {

        $subject = $params['subject'];
        $pattern = "~{$params['pattern']}~";

        preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match);

        return $match[1];
    }

}
```

The usage is now

```
{preg_match pattern='name="(.*?)"' subject=$new_item_data.content}
```

In my case, this returns the name value:

```
<select name="{preg_match pattern='name="(.*?)"' subject=$new_item_data.content}">
    <option>aaa</option>
    <option>bbb</option>
</select>
```